# Change modal class name in JavaScript under certain condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, button, bootstrap-5

Hi I'm new to JS and bootstrap, I'm trying to make a set of buttons under certain condition, in this case, if the item-quantity > 3, then the related plus button will be disabled.
However, it didn't work as expected, if I clicked the first plus button, it will disable the thrid one. I also attched a image to illustrate this problem below.

```js
var plusCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("plus");
for (var i = 0; i < plusCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
  var buttonp = plusCartItemButtons[i];
  buttonp.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    var quantityElement = buttonClicked.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("item-quantity")[0];
    if (parseFloat(quantityElement.innerText) < 3) {
      quantityElement.innerText = parseFloat(quantityElement.innerText) + 1;
      // updateCartTotal();
    } else {
      buttonp.classList.add('disabled');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-items">
  <div class="row cart-row" id="cart-row2">
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="cart-item-img"><img src="assets/vegetable.jpg" style="width:100px"></div>
      <span class="cart-item-title">Vegetable</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="price">$16</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm minus">-</button>
        <span class="item-quantity">1</span>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm plus">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">Delete</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row cart-row" id="cart-row2">
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="cart-item-img"><img src="assets/asparagus.jpg" style="width:100px"></div>
      <span class="cart-item-title">Asparagus Steak</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="price">$20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom ">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm minus">-</button>
        <span class="item-quantity">1</span>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm plus">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">Delete</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row cart-row" id="cart-row3">
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="cart-item-img"><img src="assets/breakfast.jpg" style="width:100px"></div>
      <span class="cart-item-title">Breakfast</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="price">$12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 border-bottom">
      <div class="box">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm minus">-</button>
        <span class="item-quantity">1</span>
        <!--use span than div to keep them inline-->
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm plus">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">Delete</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Problem image**

[image: Problem image]

As illustrated above, I applied the for loop and if statement, then the classList.add() to make this function, but it didn't work as expected.
Could anyone help me with this problem? I'll be really appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `let buttonp =` instead of `var buttonp =` (see link above for details). It's best to use `let`/`const` these days. `var` is rarely/never really needed and usually doesn't behave how you would expect a variable to behave.

Comment: Hi, Nick. It works! really appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries :) - I also updated your question to use a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). For future questions you can create these to easily show your issue (and remove redundant code that isn't relevant to reproducing the issue such as `<img>` tags in this case, call to `updateCartTotal()`, and even `class` names) .

Comment: Hi Nick, I got that, really appreciate your suggestions.